# Problem passing information from activities

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

Same as my last question, I'm building custom contacts app which saved the contacts on the app only.
I've encountered an issue from creating a contact and viewing it.
Whenever I click on "OK" on the new contact screen, instead of opening the activity with the input, I'm being pushed back to contact list.

I've seen countless of questions here about problem passing information from activity to another, yet it didn't help me.
I've switched from `startActivity(intent)` to `startActivityForResult(moverIntent,1);`
I've tried using `putExtra()` to each string instead of `bundle`.
I've tried to send only 1 string instead of 4 and still didn't work.

The `AddNewActivity.java`:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addcontact);

        ok=findViewById(R.id.okIB);
        not_ok=findViewById(R.id.notokIB);

        fullName=findViewById(R.id.fullnameET);
        nickName=findViewById(R.id.nicknameET);
        email=findViewById(R.id.emailET);
        phoneNum=findViewById(R.id.phoneET);

        final String name,nick,emaill,phone;
        name=fullName.getText().toString();
        nick=nickName.getText().toString();
        emaill=email.getText().toString();
        phone=phoneNum.getText().toString();


        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ok.setImageResource(R.drawable.okpress);
                Intent moverIntent=new Intent(AddNewActivity.this,ContactActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("fullName",name);
                bundle.putString("nickName",nick);
                bundle.putString("email",emaill);
                bundle.putString("phoneNum",phone);
                moverIntent.putExtras(bundle);

                startActivityForResult(moverIntent,1);

            }
        });
```

The `ContactActivity.java`:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

        //Intent get_info=getIntent(); //Previous attempt of getting the Bundle
        Bundle old_info= getIntent().getExtras();
        final String phone_num,full_name,nick_name,email_add;

        phone_num=old_info.getString("phoneNum");
        full_name=old_info.getString("fullName");
        nick_name=old_info.getString("nickName");
        email_add=old_info.getString("email");

        pic_btn=findViewById(R.id.take_pic);
        date_btn=findViewById(R.id.take_date);
        call_btn=findViewById(R.id.take_call);
        sms_btn=findViewById(R.id.send_sms);
        phone=findViewById(R.id.contact_phoneTV);
        name=findViewById(R.id.contact_nameTV);
        nick=findViewById(R.id.nick_nameTV);
        email=findViewById(R.id.emailTV);

        phone.setText(phone_num);
        name.setText(full_name);
        nick.setText(nick_name);
        email.setText(email_add);
```

Based on what I've learned and read here, I have expected that the activity `ContactActivity` to be open and display all the information from the `AddNewActivity`, what does happen is that I'm being thrown back to the list activity (didn't post it here).

Comment: provide previous question link

Comment: the previous question doesn't really has to do with this one, I was just saying that it's the same project

Comment: check the manifest

Comment: manifest was set up correctly, verified just now..

Comment: please check you logcat: this problem can be happen if there's a crash in  the ContactActivity, maybe the getIntent() return null value (put if (getIntent() !=null) before getting your Intent)  or maybe you didn't add ContactActivity to your activity

Comment: @Ezaldeen sahb - did the if statement - same result. about the other stuff, where didn't I added ContactActivity? that's the activity which suppose to open

Comment: Sorry I meant to your manifest file